# Accessing nsIAccessibleText XPCOM Interface

Tags: firefox, xpcom

I am trying to use the getCharacterExtents() method on the nsIAccessibleText XPCOM Interface. Unfortunately I can not get any documentation on how to query this interface.

```
let accessibleService  = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/accessibilityService;1"].createInstance(),
    nsIAccessibilityService = accessibleService.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIAccessibilityService);
```

Obviously this fails.
How can I query the `nsIAccessibleText` interface and use `getCharacterExtents` method?

Here is the MDN documentation on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIAccessibleText

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after banging my head around I manage to get this working. Got some help from some Victor Porof and other mozillians from IRC.

```
let accService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/accessibleRetrieval;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIAccessibleRetrieval),
acc = accService.getAccessibleFor(aNode),
nsIAccessibleText = acc.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIAccessibleText)
// aNode is a DOM node in pres shell 0
```

Hope this helps someone.